# replace a variable's value if it contains a certain string

Tags: regex, stata

I have a variable called `diagnosis` and I want to replace everything that contains the word "pneumonia" with just "pneumonia"

I tried this:

```
replace diagnosis = "Pneumonia" if regexm (diagnosis, "pneumonia")
```

But I got an error: unrecognized command: regexm

I have Stata/IC version 12.1 for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:**

take out the space between `regexm` and `(diagnosis, "pneumonia")`

**Additional suggestions:**

`regexm` takes a long time, so I would do something more like

```
replace diagnosis = "Pneumonia" if diagnosis == "pneumonia"
```

which achieves the same result, or if you want to do this more generally you can write

```
replace diagnosis = strproper(diagnosis)
```

which has the same results in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach.

```
. clonevar newdiag = diag

. replace newdiag = "pneumonia" if strpos(strlower(diag),"pneumonia")>0
(3 real changes made)

. list, clean noobs

                   diag     newdiag  
              pneumonia   pneumonia  
              Pneumonia   pneumonia  
    Bronchial pneumonia   pneumonia  
      Flu and pneumonia   pneumonia  
                earache     earache
```